# JOIN table BY date does not display appropriate data in second table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables in my database that I want to merge into one with a join table:

plan:

| id | c_project | plan | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | P001 | 20 | 2021-12-25 |
| 2 | P001 | 25 | 2022-01-07 |

actual:

| id | c_project | actual | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | P001 | 30 | 2021-12-25 |
| 2 | P001 | 35 | 2022-01-07 |

My JOIN table query:

```
SELECT a.`p_code`, plan, actual, a.`date`
FROM plan AS a 
JOIN actual AS b
ON a.`p_code` = b.`p_code`
GROUP BY a.`p_code`, a.`date`
ORDER BY a.`date` ASC
```

I have a problem with the output generated, that the actual data in the **actual table** is only the **first date period** that is displayed:

| id | c_project | plan | actual | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | P001 | 20 | 30 | 2021-12-25 |
| 2 | P001 | 25 | 30 | 2022-01-07 |

How can I do to improve my query above to get output like this:

| id | c_project | plan | actual | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | P001 | 20 | 30 | 2021-12-25 |
| 2 | P001 | 25 | 35 | 2022-01-07 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error related to only\_full\_group\_by when executing a query in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql)

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] [mre] PS Please look at the formatted version of your post before you publish. Please format code reasonably.

Comment: *```ON a.p_code = b.p_code```* No such column in your tables.

Comment: ```.. FROM plan JOIN actual USING (c_project, date) ..``` ?

Comment: sorry there was an error in writing, I mean c_project , now my problem has been solved, thanks for the help from everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider join by date columns aswell

```
SELECT a.`p_code`, plan, actual, a.`date`
   FROM plan AS a 
   JOIN actual AS b
ON a.`p_code` = b.`p_code` and a.`date` = b.`date`
GROUP BY a.`p_code`, a.`date`
ORDER BY a.`date` ASC
```